# How to solve mixed-integer problem?

Tags: inequality, integer-programming, ceiling-and-floor-functions, mixed-integer-programming

I don't know how to solve this equation,

$$\left\lceil\frac{x-A}{B}\right\rceil C + D x < E, \quad x\in \mathbb{Z}$$

In this equation, only $x$ is unknown and $x$ is integer, but $A,B,C,D,E$ are maybe decimals and they are greater than zero. How can I get the upper bound of $x$?

Answer (score 1):

Introduce an integer variable $y$ and a continuous variable $s$, and write:
$$\begin{align}
  & y C + Dx \le E\\
  &y = \frac{x-A}{B} + s \\
  &s \in [0,0.999] \\
  &y \in \{...,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,...\}
\end{align}$$
Of course a $<$ constraint is no good, so I made it a $\le$ constraint.

Comment: You should have asked whether the strict inequality is intended, because it changes the answer: $\lceil a\rceil < b$ is equivalent to $a \leq b-1$, which means that the slack variable is unnecessary. In other words, you have answered a slightly different question than what was asked.

Comment: Claim $\lceil a \rceil < b \Rightarrow a \le b-1$. Counter example: $b=1.5$

Comment: Ah, yes, I was confused. That only works if $b$ is integral. Otherwise we have $a \leq\lfloor b\rfloor$, but that only works when $b$ is not integral. So that doesn't help, as checking for integrality is at least as hard as modeling a strict inequality. Fair enough. I do think that replacing the strict inequality by a non-strict one deserves an argument, though.

Comment: I don't think so. In optimization, we should never use $<$ except if **everything** in the constraint is 100% integer valued. I think you are just confusing the issue more than being helpful.

Comment: Yes, but I think at least mentioning _why_ would be helpful in this context.

Comment: Although, to be completely fair, the reason I came here is because your blog post about this answer got cited [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/a/513/). In this context, removing the $<$ definitely needs an argument, but that omission is the responsibility of the one who cited you there, and not on you. So I may be giving this issue more importance than it deserves in this context.